# NuGet: Force project to chose more specific target framework over netstandard

Tags: nuget, .net-standard

**Short Version**

I author a package which targets .NET Standard 1.3 and 1.6. My 1.6 build references `System.Runtime.Loader`. This package has a [placeholder](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2237#issue-234893294) for the MonoAndroid framework, meaning my NuGet package now can not be loaded in Android 7.x projects.

My .NET Standard 1.3 build does not have this dependency. How can I force NuGet to load the netstandard-1.3 build for Android projects, instead of netstandard-1.6?

**More Details**

When I try and load our current package in an Android 7 project which uses project.json, I see the below error message:

```
System.Runtime.Loader 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Runtime.Loader on MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win.
```

My understanding, is that this is caused by the [System.Runtime.Loader NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Loader/) using placeholders for a number of the target frameworks. The structure of this package, is as such:

```
lib -> netstandard1.5 -> System.Runtime.Loader.dll
       MonoAndroid10  -> _._
```

I also package a netstandard-1.3 build of my package, which does not reference the System.Runtime.Loader assembly. I'm happy for Android users to get the reduced functionality in the 1.3 build - but I can't figure out how to force NuGet to pick this framework, over .NET Standard 1.6.

My current package structure is below:

```
lib -> netstandard1.3 -> build13.dll
       netstandard1.6 -> build16.dll
```

I've attempted to change it to the below - to force NuGet to pick the more specific target framework, but NuGet seems to prefer netstandard1.6 over MonoAndroid. (I've also tried MonoAndroid10)

```
lib -> netstandard1.3 -> build13.dll
       MonoAndroid    -> build13.dll
       netstandard1.6 -> build16.dll
```

Is there any way, as a package author, I can force my downstream users' Android projects to use the .NET Standard 1.3 build of my project, instead of the 1.6 build, which fails to restore due to the placeholder items in the System.Runtime.Loader package?

Comment: NuGet should pick the more specific target framework over netstandard if a more specific target framework exists. If that is not happening then I would capture the NuGet output and open a bug on http://github.com/nuget/home/issues

Comment: @Chris when you changed to package to include a dll for `MonoAndroid`, did you also update the nuspec to include a dependency group for the mono android version? Also, it should be `MonoAndroid10` in that case.

Comment: @MartinUllrich I did. I noticed the generated nuspec changed the tfm from `MonoAndroid10` (which I typed) to `MonoAndroid1.0` - I don't know if there's any relevance there.

Comment: @MattWard - thanks for the confirmation - I thought this was how it _should_ work - but wasn't totally sure. If I'm not missing anything obvious, I'll double check tonight, and open a bug report.

Comment: Thanks both. I've opened a bug report here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5759  Will update the question if I get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found this was a caching problem.

Everything I assumed about how NuGet should work was correct. The issue was that NuGet appears to cache package dependencies, so when I was rebuilding my package, it was still using the old dependency list. Annoyingly, this is only an internal cache - the Visual Studio UI made it appear that my new package's dependencies were being recognised correctly, yet the logs were showing the old dependencies being installed.

The solution was to clear the NuGet cache between each repackage.